# SQL Query Error #1093 - Can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, wordpress

In my WordPress DB I am executing a version of this more simplified query:

```
    UPDATE wp_postmeta a
    SET    a.meta_value = 'roses'
    WHERE  a.meta_key = 'flowers' AND
           EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   wp_postmeta b
                   WHERE  a.post_id = b.post_id AND 
                          b.meta_key = 'month' AND 
                          b.meta_value = 'august')
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
   #1093 - You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause
```

I have limited experience in working with DB queries to understand how to fix the query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE #1:  The answer was provided below by @Rahul.

Comment: Tag correctly **MySQL != Microsoft SQL Server**

Comment: come up with more aliases, leave `a` out of the equation in `from` chunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a `UPDATE JOIN` like below. Do a `SELF JOIN` with the same table.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta a
JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.post_id = b.post_id AND 
                      b.meta_key = 'month' AND 
                      b.meta_value = 'august'
SET    a.meta_value = 'roses'
WHERE  a.meta_key = 'flowers';
```

Comment: Rahul, thank you!!!  Your answer worked perfectly for me.